# How to display draggable text elements inside a canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

What I want is to display multiple text elements on a webpage (such as `span` or `p` elements) and when I double click them, I can turn it into an `input` element and change its text.

Each element must be **draggable**, so when I double click an element I have to create the `input` element at the same place the text element was.

**What is the best way to do this?** Inside a `canvas`? From what I've read it is not possible to have HTML elements inside a canvas.

PS: I am aware of the HTML5 `draggable` property and already used it for tests. Same for JQueryUI so the problem is not about DnD, it's just about the best way to record the position of a draggable element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To drage text element into canvas, it's a good idea to use a framework (as [cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/)).

You cannot use HTML elements inside an canvas element, but you can simulate such a behaviour by creating a text input field when the user click on the text, and add the text input at the same place as the text.

In [cgSceneGraph](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/), I use the same trick to display and manipulate a web view "inside" a canvas (but with an iFrame instead of a text input).

Here is the code to start:

```
this._textInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
this._textInput .style.position = "absolute";
document.body.appendChild(this._textInput);

this._textInput.style.left = this.getAbsoluteLeft() + "px";
this._textInput.style.top = this.getAbsoluteTop( + "px";
this._textInput.style.width = this.getAbsoluteWidth() + "px";
this._textInput.style.height = this.getAbsoluteHeight() + "px";
```

Comment: It seems to be a good framework too from what I've read! (from your link to its website). I will give it a try to choose the one which best fits my needs, thank you.

Comment: I am currently trying cgSceneGraph, It's nice. I have two questions: Can I remove the pink border when a node is being dragged? And how do I bind the `dblclick` event on a textNode? By extending the class?

Comment: Yes, you can modify the behaviour of the selected bounding box with those 4 properties of a CGSGNode: `selectionHandleColor`, `selectionHandleSize`, `selectionLineColor` and `selectionLineWidth`. The v2 will also include a delegate rendering method to draw anything you want instead of the squares. Every node inherid from the CGSGNode and so get all the events and properties from it. The double click event (also work as double touch, which is not managed by the mobile browser natively) is called as any other event: myTextNode.onDblClick = function (event) {
//event.node.xxx; 
};`

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the ["mouse & touch" example on the web site](http://gwennaelbuchet.github.com/cgSceneGraph/examples.html). The only reason to extend CGSGNode is to create your own rendering method. And that's a good thing to do : cgSceneGraph is a plugin based framework provided with already several extensions. 
Also I suggest you to create a new question to let me explain more deeply how to manipulate events, properties and custom nodes. Hope that help :)

Comment: We finally decided to use cgSceneGraph over KineticJS for our project. Very nice framework, thank you!